# How to use a value that is specified in a function call as a "variable"

Tags: r, function, macros, sas

I am wondering if it is possible in R to use a value that is declared in a function call as a "variable" part of the function itself, similar to the functionality that is available in SAS IML.

Given something like this:

```
put.together <- function(suffix, numbers) {
new.suffix <<- as.data.frame(numbers)
return(new.suffix)
}

x <- c(seq(1000,1012, 1))
put.together(part.a, x)

new.part.a   ##### does not exist!!

new.suffix   ##### does exist
```

As it is written, the function returns a dataframe called `new.suffix`, as it should because that is what I'm asking it to do.

I would like to get a dataframe returned that is called `new.part.a`.

---

**EDIT: Additional information was requested regarding the purpose of the analysis**

The purpose of the question is to produce dataframes that will be sent to another function for analysis.

There exists a data bank where elements are organized into groups by number, and other people organize the groups
into a meaningful set.

Each group has an id number.  I use the information supplied by others to put the groups together as they are specified.

For example, I would be given a set of id numbers like:   part-1 = 102263, 102338, 202236, 302342, 902273, 102337, 402233.

So, part-1 has seven groups, each group having several elements.

I use the id numbers in a merge so that only the groups of interest are extracted from the large data bank.

The following is what I have for one set:

```
### all.possible.elements.bank <- .csv file from large database ###

id.part.1 <- as.data.frame(c(102263, 102338, 202236, 302342, 902273, 102337, 402233))
bank.names <- c("bank.id")
colnames(id.part.1) <- bank.names
part.sort <- matrix(seq(1,nrow(id.part.1),1)) 
sort.part.1 <- cbind(id.part.1, part.sort)

final.part.1 <- as.data.frame(merge(sort.part.1, all.possible.elements.bank, 
by="bank.id", all.x=TRUE))
```

The process above is repeated many, many times.

I know that I could do this for all of the collections that I would pull together, but I thought I would be able to wrap the selection process into a function.  The only things that would change would be the part numbers (part-1, part-2, etc..)  and the groups that are selected out.

Comment: This is a reasonable question, but I would also be interested in more detail about what you're trying to do so that we could suggest more R-idiomatic ways of doing it. As suggested by the answers, these macro-like approaches are deprecated in R, partly for aesthetic reasons, but also because (as also suggested below) they tend to be fragile.  I can't immediately point to a case where they fail, although once you start nesting calls to functions it gets tricky to do these approaches correctly.

Comment: @BenBolker Edits made regarding objective of the program.

Comment: don't have time to hack on this now, but the edit is very useful (I already gave +1 so I can't again ...)   I'm a little confused by your code -- `id.part.1` gets overwritten by `bank.names` before you do anything with it? Is that a typo? `nrow(id.part.1)` would then be `NULL` ... (this is why *reproducible* examples are good!  You could `dput()` a few rows of your larger data frame, for example ... If you just want to select rows corresponding to the part1 sets, then `subset(all.possible.elements.bank,bank.id %in% id.part.1)` should do it ...

Comment: @blueandgrey: The edits look like they would take this question in a totally different direction; I'd suggest opening a new question instead and leaving a link here.

Comment: If you have your part-ID strings stored in a **list** then making a function that calls `subset()` and returns the relevant rows, then putting it into `lapply()`, will give you a list of the relevant chunks.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron, I'll start a new question with a link to this one.  It certainly seems that I fell into the trap of trying to apply an old solution to a new environment.  I'll be sure to pull together fully reproducible code for an example.

Comment: @BenBolker I posted a new question showing what I want to do as opposed to making a method work.  The question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840509/how-to-create-a-function-where-the-arguments-passed-to-it-vary).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible using the `assign` function (and possibly `deparse` and `substitute`), but it is strongly discouraged to do things like this.  Why can't you just return the data frame and call the function like:

```
new.part.a <- put.together(x)
```

Which is the generally better approach.

If you really want to change things in the global environment then you may want a macro, see the `defmacro` function in the `gtools` package and most importantly read the document in the refrences section on the help page.

Comment: That was the motivation for the question.  I have many such statements (like in your answer) written already, and was wondering if there was a way to clean them up.  I guess the short answer is no...

Answer (score 1):

This is rarely something you should want to do... assigning to things out of the function environment can get you into all sorts of trouble.

However, you can do it using `assign`:

```
put.together <- function(suffix, numbers) {
   assign(paste('new',
                deparse(substitute(suffix)),
                sep='.'),
          as.data.frame(numbers),
          envir=parent.env(environment()))
}

put.together(part.a, 1:20)
```

But like Greg said, its usually not necessary, and always dangerous if used incorrectly.

Comment: To answer the precise question asked by the OP, I think you want `deparse(substitute(suffix))` (as hinted at by @GregSnow) rather than `suffix`.  Also, you might use `parent.env()` instead of `.GlobalEnv` (although if the OP tries to do this sort of thing within nested environments they will probably be in trouble anyway).

Comment: Thanks all for your comments.  Looks like it may be more trouble than it's worth...