# How to create a function for subsetting data where the arguments passed to it vary

Tags: r, function

This is a follow-up question related to [my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9829424/how-to-use-a-value-that-is-specified-in-a-function-call-as-a-variable).  Below is a more explanatory version of "what I want to do" as opposed to "how do I make this method work".

Below is code that produces a "master" database, from which, I extract elements for further use in other functions. I routinely extract elements of data based on the value of a group identification number.

- Objective:  I would like to be able to "wrap" the specifications that vary (like the name of the output dataframe and the groups selected) into a function that could be called.

---

```
#####  generating data for example

set.seed(271828)

n.elements <- c(10,10,12,14,16,18)
group.number <- rep(1001:1006, n.elements)
element.id <- c(
    seq(1,n.elements[1], 1),
    seq(1,n.elements[2], 1),
    seq(1,n.elements[3], 1), 
    seq(1,n.elements[4], 1),
    seq(1,n.elements[5], 1),
    seq(1,n.elements[6], 1) ) 

x1 <- round(rnorm(length(group.number),45, 12), digits=0)
x2 <- round(rbeta(length(group.number),2,4), digits = 2)

data.base <- as.data.frame(cbind(group.number, element.id, x1, x2))
data.base

#####  data.base is representative of the large database 


#####  suppose I need to pull a set together made up of groups: 
#####  1003, 1004, and 1001 


groups.set.1 <- as.data.frame(c(1003, 1004, 1001))
bank.names <- c("group.number")
colnames(groups.set.1) <- bank.names
set.sort <- matrix(seq(1,nrow(groups.set.1),1)) 
sort.set.1 <- cbind(groups.set.1, set.sort)

set.1 <- as.data.frame(merge(sort.set.1, data.base, 
by="group.number", all.x=TRUE))

#####  this is how the dataset needs to be ordered for further use
set.1 <- set.1[order(set.1$set.sort, set.1$element.id ), ]
row.names(set.1) <- seq(nrow(set.1))
```

---

**EDIT:** Suppose I wanted to carry out the same task to produce `set.2`, where `set.2` is made up of groups: 1005, 1006, and 1002.  I could just copy the above code, and make the relevant changes.  However, I would like to know if it is possible to specify a function so that I can pass the necessary changes to it, and have it produce the output dataframe as desired.  Perhaps having a function called `group.extract`, where I could specify something like the following:

```
groups.2 <- c(1005, 1006, 1002)
group.extract(set.2, groups.2)
```

Based on the comments provided, it seems like a list is the way to go, and have the function call the list, where the list elements can vary.

Comment: Take a look at `?assign`, which allows you to assign a value to a name, with the name possibly obtained from an argument in your function. Would that get you started? So like `function(mySet1="set.1")assign(mySet1,42)`, being careful of environments of course. EDIT: ...as mentioned in the answers to your previous post.

Comment: I'm still not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but from the words you're using to describe it it seems like you might try either passing a list (whose contents could be everything that you want to pass) or using the `...` functionality.

Comment: @gsk3 Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm working on this now, but I think your idea is the way to go.

Comment: The example code is clear, but the words, and especially the title, confuse the issue; a new title may be in order, perhaps something like "How to get a subset of data in a specific order by writing a function?"

Comment: @Aaron  Title of question updated as requested.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm still not sure what "arguments pass to it vary" means though; it sounds like you want a function that will do different things based on what kind of argument you pass it.  But here, you're always passing it the same kind of thing.  Unless I'm misunderstanding, I'd suggest removing that phrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd write this function using `match`, as follows.  Here I've hard-coded the names of the columns of the input data frame to use for matching and sorting; those could also be added as optional inputs.  The column order of the output is slightly different from yours but that could be easily changed as well.

```
getset <- function(g, d=data.base) {
  d$set.sort <- match(d$group.number, g)
  d <- d[!is.na(d$set.sort),]
  d <- d[order(d$set.sort, d$element.id),]
  rownames(d) <- NULL
  d
}
```

You'd use it almost exactly like you propose:

```
> set.1 <- getset(c(1003, 1004, 1001))
> head(set.1)
  group.number element.id x1   x2 set.sort
1         1003          1 60 0.32        1
2         1003          2 28 0.18        1
3         1003          3 42 0.47        1
4         1003          4 43 0.08        1
5         1003          5 45 0.31        1
6         1003          6 27 0.48        1
```

Though if you have multiple groups to get, putting them in a list and using `lapply` would be the way to go.

```
> groups <- list(group1=c(1003, 1004, 1001), group2=c(1005,1006,1002))
> sets <- lapply(groups, getset)
> lapply(sets, head)
$group1
  group.number element.id x1   x2 set.sort
1         1003          1 60 0.32        1
2         1003          2 28 0.18        1
3         1003          3 42 0.47        1
4         1003          4 43 0.08        1
5         1003          5 45 0.31        1
6         1003          6 27 0.48        1

$group2
  group.number element.id x1   x2 set.sort
1         1005          1 27 0.20        1
2         1005          2 51 0.48        1
3         1005          3 49 0.43        1
4         1005          4 48 0.20        1
5         1005          5 33 0.37        1
6         1005          6 41 0.50        1
```

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully reviewing the code in SO can effect a cure for what appears to be a moderately severe case of post-SAS-ism. I think this is a more R-ish way of doing this:

```
 pick <-  subset(data.base, group.number %in% c(1003, 1004, 1001) )
 idx <- match(pick$group.number,  c(1003, 1004, 1001) ) 
 pick[ order(idx, pick$element.id), ]
 #---------
   group.number element.id x1   x2
21         1003          1 60 0.32
22         1003          2 28 0.18
23         1003          3 42 0.47
24         1003          4 43 0.08
25         1003          5 45 0.31
26         1003          6 27 0.48 
snipped----
```

And this would be that strategy incorporated into a function:

```
grp.ext.srt <- function(dfrm, grpid) { pick <-  dfrm[ group.number %in% grpid , ]
     idx <- match(pick$group.number,  grpid ) ; rownames(pick) <- NULL
     return(pick[ order(idx, pick$element.id), ])
      }
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  I've been SAS-free for a few years, but my new job uses it quite a bit.  I am definitely the R loner / advocate here, but I feel that I'm gaining a following...